# Обьединить две строки в датафрейме в одну

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Есть вот такой датафрейм

```
    Номертижня      Деньтижня     Пара      1 група
    Перший тиждень    Понеділок     1       Лб1 Практичний курс"Бізнес-симуляція"
                                              вул.Чигоріна,57-а .
                                2       Лб1 Практичний курс"Бізнес-симуляція"
                                              вул.Чигоріна,57-а .
                                3   
...
```

Возможно ли преобразовать его в следующий вид:

```
    Номертижня      Деньтижня     Пара      1 група
    Перший тиждень    Понеділок     1       Лб1 Практичний курс"Бізнес-симуляція" вул.Чигоріна,57-а.
                                2       Лб1 Практичний курс"Бізнес-симуляція" вул.Чигоріна,57-а.     
                                3   
...
```

Comment: А это в виде чего? Ну то есть на входе такой `csv` файл или это готовый `Pandas DataFrame` после каких-то преобразований?

Comment: датафрейм после обработки скачанного с сайта xlsx файла

Comment: Я в том смысле, что не проще ли обработку починить, чем бороться с её последствиями? Или там сам `xlsx` файл такой был?

Comment: Сам файл такой кривой, слишком много там всего напихано для обработки вручную, нужно автоматизировать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вся структура датафрейма такая, как на приведённом фрагменте, то можно просто объединить нужную колонку, использовав сдвиг, а затем выкинуть лишние строки, примерно так:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, '', 2, '', 3, ''], 'y': list('abcdef')})
df['y'] = df['y'] + ' ' + df.shift(-1)['y']
df = df.loc[df['x'] != '']
df
```

Исходный датафрейм:

```
    x   y
0   1   a
1       b
2   2   c
3       d
4   3   e
5       f
```

На выходе:

```
    x     y
0   1   a b
2   2   c d
4   3   e f
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно