# Объединить строки в датафрейме

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.9

Ранее я задавал вопрос похожий вопрос, вот ссылка: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1337501/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83/1340526#1340526), но не учёл что может встретится следующий прикол.

Пересматривая датафрейм, я наткнулся на такую штуку:

```
    Номертижня      Деньтижня     Пара      1 група
    Перший тиждень    П'ятниця      1       Лб1 Практичний курс"Бізнес-симуляція"
                                              вул.Чигоріна,57-а .
                                    2       Лб1 Практичний курс"Бізнес-симуляція"
                                              вул.Чигоріна,57-а .
                                    3       Лб2 Безпека ІнфСист та мереж 
                                            Б-520   доц. yyyy .
                                            Лб1 Безпека ІнфСист та мереж
                                            Б-514   проф. xxxx.
```

Это деление груп на подгруппы, такое деление встречается не всегда, оно может быть, а может и не быть вообще.
Можно ли как-то это сделать таким образом:

```
    Номертижня      Деньтижня     Пара      1 група
    Перший тиждень    П'ятниця      1       Лб1 Практичний курс"Бізнес-симуляція" вул.Чигоріна,57-а                 
                                    2       Лб1 Практичний курс"Бізнес-симуляція" вул.Чигоріна,57-а .        
                                    3       Лб2 Безпека ІнфСист та мереж Б-520 доц. yyyy. / Лб1 Безпека ІнфСист та мереж Б-514   проф. xxxx.
```

Comment: я так понимаю, описание групп у вас на разных строках датафрейма? а в тех строках столбца "пара", где ничего нет - там что? пробел или NaN?

Comment: Да, описание на разных строках, а в столбце пара на пустых значениях отображается NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, в этом случае вам подойдет обычная группировка. При df:

```
     x    y  z
0    1  1.0  a
1    2  2.0  d
2  NaN  NaN  e
3  NaN  2.0  f
4    3  3.0  g
5  NaN  NaN  h
6  NaN  3.0  j
```

группируем:

```
res = df.fillna(method = 'ffill')
res = res.groupby(['x', 'y'])['z'].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x)).reset_index()
```

**UPDATE**

Если в колонке с описанием группы могут попадаться пустые значения, можно сделать так:

```
df[['x', 'y']] = df[['x', 'y']].fillna(method = 'ffill')
res = df.groupby(['x', 'y'])['z'].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x)).reset_index()
```

получаем res:

```
   x    y      z
0  1  1.0      a
1  2  2.0  d/e/f
2  3  3.0  g/h/j​
```

Comment: Не совсем то, что хотелось бы, код сортирует по алфавиту, сначала первую колонку по алфавиту, потом вторую. 
Кроме того, пустые места в расписании заполняет левыми данными.
https://imgur.com/7gkzRXB - вот на скрине отметил

Comment: сортировку всегда можно поменять так, как вам  нужно. Что касается заполнения колонки с группами, я обновил ответ. Как вы понимаете, очень не достает  воспроизводимого примера исходных данных в вопросе. Как этого требуют правила сайта, между прочим.

Comment: https://github.com/Nick-Alskling/test/blob/main/test.py , вот я добавил файл на гитхаб, если можете, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: вы можете выложить промежуточный датафрейм, с которым у вас возникли проблемы в данном вопросе?